# Coprimes - assumption and required proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We have three numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$.

There them $gcd(a, b) = 1$ and $gcd(a, c) = 1$ and $gcd(b, c) = 1$ (coprimes).

It must be shown that there are an infinitely many $k$ such that $gcd(a, k) = 1$ and $gcd(b, k) = 1$, and $gcd(c, k) = 1$ (a, b, c, k are coprime) and $k$ is not a prime.

The assumption seems obvious to me but someone might try to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e=abc$. Since there are infinitely many primes $\{p_i\}_{\infty}$ such that $m>n \implies p_m>p_n$, let $j$ be such that $p_j>e$. Then for any $k,l>j$ you get $\gcd(a,p_kp_l)=1$, $\gcd(b,p_kp_l)=1$ and $\gcd(c,p_kp_l)=1$.

Note that you don't need any assumptions about $a$, $b$, $c$.

Also the $\{p_i\}_\infty$ should just be thought of as the enumeration of all primes in ascending order.